Azure: Cannot remove orphaned role assignations for a deleted role
I created a role for my Azure subscription and assigned some users to it. Later I decided to delete it and somehow Azure let me do it without removing the role assignations first. Now I have 3 assignations that I cannot remove because the role does not exist.
While inspecting the network tab I see that the call to /providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests/{roleEligibilityScheduleRequestsName}?api-version=2020-10-01 fails with the following response:
{"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"The resource is not found."}}

As you can see, I get a notification that the assignation were removed succesfully

But after refreshing the page the assignation is still there

If I click on the role, I get a screen with an error because it does not exists

As you can see. The error is accurate because the role does not exist


I also tried using the Role Eligibility Schedule API but all I get in response is a 500 response with a very brief An error has ocurred message.

Could you include how you assigned the roles to users?

In my case, deleting custom role definition deleted role assignments too

@Sridevi I added them by clicking "add role assignation" in the subscription, selecting the role, and then selecting the users. The type of assignment is time bound.

Could you try changing the browsers or sign in via incognito windows and check if it's updated or not?

I tried logging in with a different browser and the role assignment is still there

Could you edit your question and add Portal images to confirm whether role definition is deleted or still showing under roles filtering with custom role?

Done. I added a screenshot of the Roles tab

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sounds good! Let's continue there
